# com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: Missing required param: amount.; request-id: req_6mshZrGwQeiE8c?

Tags: java, stripe-payments, playframework-2.4

I integrated Strip java api to my play framework.
I am calling create() method on Charge class and at the same time exception is comming.
This is my code :

```
Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2";
    Logger.debug("stripeToken"+form.data().get("stripeToken"));

    final Map<String,Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    chargeParams.put("amount", 20);
    chargeParams.put("currency", "usd");
    //chargeParams.put("source","tok_16YxZe2eZvKYlo2C3nzXof9N" ); // obtained with Stripe.js
    chargeParams.put("source", form.data().get("stripeToken"));
    chargeParams.put("description", "Charge for test@example.com");


    try {
        final RequestOptions options = RequestOptions
                .builder()
                .setIdempotencyKey("tGW5MOnasgR1ezw4")
                .build();


        final Charge chargeresponse = Charge.create(chargeParams,options);

    } catch (AuthenticationException | InvalidRequestException | APIConnectionException | CardException
            | APIException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Source link
[Java Api](https://stripe.com/docs/api/java#charge_object)

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error here is that you are passing `20` in the `amount` parameter. This parameter expects a value in cents which means you are trying to charge $0.20 which is not supported at Stripe as the [minimum](https://support.stripe.com/questions/what-is-the-minimum-amount-i-can-charge-with-stripe) amount you can charge is $0.50.

If you pass 50 (or more) in that parameter it should work as expected.

EDIT: The error should not be this though, when I try I get "Amount must be at least 50 cents" so not sure what's causing this on your end but I think that's the issue.

Comment: I don't know i tried before with keeping with the different amount ,it was not working then i tried with a stand alone application and found its working in that , and replicate the the same code and its started working....   Thanks though for your time.